# eclipse pdt debugger won't terminate, it starts up on its own after finishing or manual termination

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-pdt, perspectives

I press the stop button and the debugger terminates .  Then a couple seconds later it restarts on its own from the beginning, continually!  How do you stop this monster?

I have looked through the help user guides and through the preferences on debugging, and found absolutely nothing related.

Changing this option from always to never did not help:

```
Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Perspectives -> Open the associated perspective when application suspends
```

Even in PHP perspective, the consol pops up automatically and starts the debug, with the following line:

```
Remote debug [Remote PHP launch] http://localhost/...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, must have screwed everything up when I changed the settings in preferences.  I had to finally resolve this by deleting the entire workspace folder and restarting eclipse.